# qsub: how to pass argument to perl script called within a shell script

Tags: linux, perl, qsub

Here is what is in the cwd:

> blastn_build.sh  qscript

They are both currently set to executable (but not binary)

Here are the contents of blastn_build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
update_blastdb.pl --showall
```

Here are the contents of qscript:

```
qsub -S /bin/bash -V -b n -N nt_wgs_build -pe smp 8 -j y  -o ./nt_wgs_build.sge -l h=n10 -cwd -sync y "./blastn_build.sh"
```

update_blastdb.pl is in my PATH and begins with #!/usr/bin/perl

---

Now the problem:

Running ./blastn_build.sh works as expected. 
Running ./qscript does not... here is the error message:

> Failed to connect to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov: Invalid argument

If I remove the --showall argument from ./blastn_build.sh then BOTH ./blastn_build.sh AND ./qscript work as expected. The issue seems to be in how to correctly pass the --showall option to update_blastdb.pl through qsub.

Any help understand and fixing would be much appreciated!

update_blastdb.pl (blast-2.2.31 http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK52640/)
wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/LATEST/ncbi-blast-2.2.31+-x64-linux.tar.gz

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# $Id: update_blastdb.pl 446090 2014-09-11 12:12:27Z ivanov $
===========================================================================
#
# Author:  Christiam Camacho
#
# File Description:
#   Script to download the pre-formatted BLAST databases from the NCBI ftp
#   server.
#
#        

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;
use File::stat;
use Digest::MD5;
use Archive::Tar;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

use constant NCBI_FTP => "ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov";
use constant BLAST_DB_DIR => "/blast/db";
use constant USER => "anonymous";
use constant PASSWORD => "anonymous";
use constant DEBUG => 0;
use constant MAX_DOWNLOAD_ATTEMPTS => 3;
use constant EXIT_FAILURE => 2;

# Process command line options
my $opt_verbose = 1;
my $opt_quiet = 0;
my $opt_force_download = 0;
my $opt_help = 0;
my $opt_passive = 0;
my $opt_timeout = 120;
my $opt_showall = 0;
my $opt_show_version = 0;
my $opt_decompress = 0;
my $result = GetOptions("verbose+"      =>  \$opt_verbose,
                    "quiet"         =>  \$opt_quiet,
                    "force"         =>  \$opt_force_download,
                    "passive"       =>  \$opt_passive,
                    "timeout=i"     =>  \$opt_timeout,
                    "showall"       =>  \$opt_showall,
                    "version"       =>  \$opt_show_version,
                    "decompress"    =>  \$opt_decompress,
                    "help"          =>  \$opt_help);
$opt_verbose = 0 if $opt_quiet;
die "Failed to parse command line options\n" unless $result;
pod2usage({-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2}) if $opt_help;
pod2usage({-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2}) unless (scalar @ARGV or
                                              $opt_showall or
                                              $opt_show_version);
#rest of code continues...
```

perl v 5.10.1

Comment: Without knowing what `update_blastdb.pl` does, it's going to be impossible to answer. Smells like a version problem - are you sure `./blastn_build.sh` is getting passed to qsub properly? It's a relative path, so you potentially have path traversal.

Comment: @Sobrique -- I just tried changing qscript to reference the full path: "/home/10019438/blastdb/2015_11_11/blastn_build.sh" but the error persists.

Comment: What happens if you run `./update_blastdb.pl < /dev/null` from the command line?  Do you get the error?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- that gives this error:                                                                                                           stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: It appears, then, that `update_blastdb.pl` is really not designed to be run except from the terminal — for reasons that are beyond my knowledge.  It does things differently depending on how it is invoked.  The `qsub` system probably runs it without a terminal connection, which is why the `< /dev/null` test was interesting. 'Tis curious that it was `stty` that reported the error — I'm left wondering what it's up to, but I'm not curious enough to download find out. It isn't clear why the Perl is failing to connect when run from `qsub` and not from the terminal; the network shouldn't be affected.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. Fair enough. Thanks so much for your insights. This was my first time needing to use qsub, though I've used bsub and sbatch, and it just really seemed that my setup was correct. So, if it is an issue with update_blastdb.pl rather than a more fundamental problem, then I think I can live with that.

Comment: Sounds to me like the `--showall` option enables functionality which requires a network connection, which apparently isn't available in the environment where `qsub` runs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are actually working in some cluster environment (or what else is qsub?). In such place your qsubed script actually runs on different node, which can have no internet connection, can execute your script starting from different directory, or can have many other misconfigures from tour original host...

Comment: You were totally correct. Many thanks to everyone who helped me troubleshoot. Things are rolling much smoother now.